# Serialize linq to sql result as xml

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I 'am trying to serialise some object from my linq to sql query to xml as follow:

```
MyDataContext mdc= new MyDataContext();
var local_copy_of_items = md.MyItemsTables.Where(c=>c.CityId==35).Distinct().ToList();

local_copy_of_items.SerializeToXml(Filename);
```

Where `SerializeToXml`:

```
public static void SerializeToXml<T>(this T obj, string fileName)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
    ser.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

exception:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: There was an error generating the XML document.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o)
   at .....Extensions.SerializeToXml[T](T obj, String fileName)
```

This code fails with InvalidOperationException .  Can someone suggest a better / correct way to achieve this?

Update: The inner exceptions says:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type

Comment: Yes. I only have a runtime error....

Comment: Which line is failing?

Comment: This is not my actual code. So any typo here might noth show exactly what i'm doing. The code compiles with only a runtime error. I just showed the idea of what i'm doing and i hope this makes sense.

Comment: Does this code fail for you as well?

Comment: Invalidacasexception inside the serilize extension method.

Comment: The code does compile well. No compile time issues. Only runtime isssue (InvalidCastexception)

Comment: Could you please post the complete exception message?

Comment: Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: There was an error generating the XML document.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream, Object o)
   at ....Extensions.SerializeToXml[T](T obj, String fileName

Answer (score 1):

According to [XmlSerializer.Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bdxxw552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `The XmlSerializer cannot serialize the following: arrays of ArrayList and arrays of List<T>.` So maybe using ToArray() instead of ToList() could help here.

Comment: I try and serialize different kind of entities and some of them do fail while others work. It seems that it has something to do with object graph.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is your problem:

```
local_copy_of_items.SerializeToXml("path",Filename);
```

It looks like you're using a generic extension method to serialize your object (very cool btw), but I think what you want to do is this:

```
local_copy_of_items.SerializeToXml(Filename);
```

Your extension method only accepts one parameter when called: the file name you want to dump your object into. The first parameter, this T obj, you never have to actually pass, it just represents the object that you are calling the method from.

Comment: sorry that is not the problem. The code compiles and does try to serialisez the data. Only a runtime error

Comment: fair enough. Does the exception or any inner exceptions say which member failed to cast? Nullable values?